# Regex to allow lowercase alphanumberic with "-" and "_" but not includes "-_ " together

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I want to check a string validation using regex
for example
it should contains lowercase aphanumberic with `-` and `_` but not only contains `-` and `_` for example

```
   "hello_"--> true
    "Hello_" --> **false** (upper case)
    "-"     --> **false** includes only "-"
    "-"      ---> **false** includes only "_"
    "-_"     ----> **false** includes only "-_" together
    "hello1232" --> **true**
```

`[a-z0-9-_]` this is my attempt
But i want to include that the `-` or `_` should not be allowed when it coms only alone

Comment: [a-z0-9-_] this is my attempt

Comment: But i want to include that the - or _ should not be allowed when it coms only alone

Comment: Should dashes or underscores be allowed at the start of the input, i.e. should `-_-1-_-` match?

Comment: @Catalina In comments under one of answers you stated that: "*`j_-` it should gives true*" but doesn't that contradicts your title which states ".. but not includes `-_` together"? Or maybe you don't want `-_` but at the same time you allow `_-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[a-z0-9]+[-_]*[a-z0-9]*$
```

---

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/b5I5ly/1)

Comment: if the string starts with [-_] it wouldn't match

Comment: @Catalina as Leyffda mentioned, (if the string starts with [-_] it wouldn't match) do you have a case like that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will also match a string with both 'minus' and underscore. For example, "hello-_".

Comment: @Alex the OP not mention that it should match only _ or - !

Comment: @YCF_L alex is right, could you please cover that case as well? "hello-_" should not be accepted, either "hello-hello" or "hello_hello" or numbers but not "hello _- hello" big thanks

Comment: @Catalina try this `^[a-z0-9]+[-_]{0,1}[a-z0-9]*$`

Comment: @YCF_L  "hello-" or "hello_"  this should also not be possible could you please update the answer, so if there is nothing after the dash and underscrore, should be false

Comment: @Catalina in your question you said `"hello_"--> true`! beside, If your requirement is changed I advice you to create a new question and we can answer you.

Comment: could you give me a hint for that?

Comment: Let me try and back to you

Comment: @Catalina did you mean `^[a-z0-9]*[-_]{0,1}[a-z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
[a-z1-9]+[-_]*
```

With a case insensitive option.

`[a-z1-9]+` means **at least one** alphanumeric character

`[-_]*` means **absence, presence, once or multiple times** of `-` **or** `_`

If you don't want it to be case insensitive but still match for upper case letters, the following should work.

```
[a-zA-Z1-9]+[-_]*
```

Comment: the check gives false for `j_-` it should gives true

Comment: @Catalina Just replace the `?` with `*`.